# When I go back and forth from the page it doesn't send post requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component where I list the policies. For example, when I come to the payment screen of the "A" policy, I send a post request. I can view the installments of policy "A". Then i go back by pressing back button in browser and go to the payment screen of policy "B". I see the installments of the "A" policy on the screen that comes up. If we refresh the page it send a post request and I can view the installments of policy "B". How do I send the post request without refreshing the page?

**service**

```
const getAsosPaymentInfo = (getPolicyAccountInfoRequestDto) => {
  return new Observable((observer) => { 
    axiosInstance
      .post(SERVICE_PATH + '/getAsosPaymentInfo', getPolicyAccountInfoRequestDto)
      .then((response) => {
        observer.next(response.data);
        observer.complete();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
};
```

**component**

```
const { paymentInfoData, setPaymentInfoData } = useContext(PaymentInfoDataContext);

useEffect(() => {
  if (Object.keys(paymentInfoData).length === 0 && props.location.state.policy.isActive === true) {
    PolicyService.getAsosInstallments(
      {
        policyNumber: props.location.state.policy.policyNumber,
        renewalNumber: props.location.state.policy.renewalNumber,
        policyTypeExtCode: props.location.state.policy.policyType.extCode,
        productTypeExtCode: props.location.state.policy.productType.extCode
      }
    ).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        setPaymentInfoData(response);
      }
    );
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: I think you need to pass your function arguments (```policyNumber, renewalNumber, policyTypeExtCode, productTypeExtCode```) into dependency array of your useEffect hook.

Also if you are using react-navigation then take a look at [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/)

Answer (score 0):

For performance optimization, React Navigation avoids mounting the screen every time the user revisited it. you need to listen to the screen focus event and then run your logic there.

React Navigation provides a hook which work with normal `useEffect`

```js
import {useIsFocused, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

// Some where inside screen

const { paymentInfoData, setPaymentInfoData } = useContext(PaymentInfoDataContext);

const isFocused = useIsFocused()
useEffect(() => {
  if (Object.keys(paymentInfoData).length === 0 && props.location.state.policy.isActive === true) {
    PolicyService.getAsosInstallments(
      {
        policyNumber: props.location.state.policy.policyNumber,
        renewalNumber: props.location.state.policy.renewalNumber,
        policyTypeExtCode: props.location.state.policy.policyType.extCode,
        productTypeExtCode: props.location.state.policy.productType.extCode
      }
    ).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        setPaymentInfoData(response);
      }
    );
  }
}, [isFocused]);
```